# Ansible add GPG Keyserver

Tags: ansible, gnupg, apt, ansible-2.x

I need to incorporate these two commands into my ansible script:

```
  # sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys #######
  # sudo gpg -a --export ####### | sudo apt-key add -
```

I am referring to this [ansible link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_key_module.html) but I am unable to produce anything that works. I tried this:

```
apt_key: keyserver=hkp://keys.gnupg.net id=######
```

and get the following error:

```
 FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: keyserver"}
```

Is there a way to properly add gpg keys with ansible?

Answer (score 4):

Check this link: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_key_module.html

```
- name: convert gpg
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys #######
    - gpg -a --export ####### | sudo apt-key add -
```